# Dependency errors for avro on Ubuntu 18.10, "Temporary failure resolving" for sudo apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.10

In 18.10, When I try to install some packges it shows `Some files can not be fetched` and for solving this when I try to install synaptic with terminal `sudo apt-get install synaptic` it returns

```
avro : Depends: libibus-1.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: ibus-clutter but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: ibus-qt4 but it is not going to be installed
 synaptic : Depends: libept1.5.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libgtk2-perl (>= 1:1.130) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: rarian-compat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

These all. Trying `sudo apt --fix-broken install` ends up with:

```
Some files can't be fetched
```

How this problem can be solved?

The output of `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 avro : Depends: libibus-1.0-dev but it is not installed
        Depends: ibus-clutter but it is not installed
        Depends: ibus-qt4 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The output of `sudo apt update`:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease           
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                  
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease [83.2 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Fetched 158 kB in 18s (8,857 B/s)  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
169 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/cosmic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

it's a problem with broken packages fact.

Comment: which type of information should be given here??

Comment: I would check you have 'universe' enabled; a pick of one random dep. shows it's present in 'universe' (https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/ibus-clutter)

Comment: Your output  clearly indicates a network problem instead of a package manager problem. Apt cannot reach the mirror. Please edit your question to tell us more about your network and ISP, and any other network problem you may coincidentally be encountering. Does your network use or require a proxy? is it a school or company network?  If a home network, does your ISP have special rules? Does *all* other normal network traffic get through properly?

Comment: I have a home broadband network, it doesn't use any proxy and yes other network traffic get through properly.

Comment: guiverc, what can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: need more explanation

Comment: @GHOST, what kind of explanation?

Comment: oops what abut your internet connection?

Comment: Its fine, i don't use any proxy or something like that. I can serve websites easily. And astonishing fact is that, i've installed ubuntu again. In fresh ubuntu i've tried to install synaptic it worked!!

Comment: I think there is a problem for using the avro installation commands or other clutter packages??

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.